# Where to download the MathWorld package?

Tags: packages, mathworld

I was trying to run some   [notebook](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/PlaneCurves/CornuSpiral.nb) I downloaded from MathWorld, but lots of them need

```
<< MathWorld`Curves`
```

I tried to google it , only to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641512/how-to-install-new-packages-for-mathematica), but the [link](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4775) links to nothing but a blank page. so where do I find these packages?

Comment: I never heard of it. Could you please specify which notebook was it you've downloaded from MathWorld and required the package?

Comment: like this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CornuSpiral.html

Comment: Thanks. I guess it must be part of the list of server-side packages, like ``"Utilities`LiveGraphics3D`"`` in e.g. [Slinky.nb](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/SpaceCurves/Slinky.nb). Best would be to write directly to Eric Weisstein, the maintainer of the site. If you do so and he replies, be sure to add an answer here!

Comment: They were there 6 months ago, I'd venture lost in the shuffle. Ping support and let them know.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know why the supporting packages were (accidentally?) removed from mathworld.wolfram.com/packages but you can still find a copy of the latest revision (2007-10-10) in the Wayback Machine archive:

- http://web.archive.org/web/20120301154256/http://library.wolfram.com:80/infocenter/MathSource/4775

Eric Weisstein's Utility Package (revision 2008-05-19) may be found at

- http://web.archive.org/web/20131519164700/http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5087/

Comment: How did you find the library in archive.org? I am having a similar problem [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116220/mathematica-5-6-oriented-graphs-code-in-mathematica-10) with OrientedGraphs.

Comment: @hhh I cannot recall with certainty but I probably found an archive.org copy of mathworld.wolfram.com, and within it found the package link.  I am incredulous that Wolfram really means to have taken down these packages yet I cannot find a current source.  Disturbingly the Notebook is, as you note, only updated for *Mathematica* 6.  It is almost as if Mathworld is becoming a deprecated resource. :-(  I suggest you edit your question to make it especially clear that although the v6 Packages are available at the link in the answer above they are not fully compatible with v10.  I will reopen.

Comment: The first link brought me to a page with the message "Item not found." Going further back in the Wayback Machine brought me to a page with the files though.

Comment: @Grayscale That's odd; I'm sure it worked when I posted this.  Thanks for the note, I'll try to correct it now.