# How can I load << MathWorld`Curves`?

Tags: plotting, mathworld

I'd like to recreate in *Wolfram Programming Cloud* the plot in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/SpaceCurves/Slinky.nb

[image]

How can I load `` << MathWorld`Curves` `` ?
Then I can paste the rest of the code and I should see the slinky?

I'm confused, thanks in advance.

Comment: This was once asked but didn't get an answer…: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43620/1871

Comment: I have all the packages, but they are not updated to new version of M. For example, this one does not run on V10.1 since it uses BeginPackage["MathWorld`Curves`",{"Utilities`FilterOptions`"}]  and  "Utilities`FilterOptions" is no longer supported, see http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/Utilities/FilterOptions.html  so even if get these files, someone needs to update them to run in new M. May be contact the original author and see if there is newer version. The Mathworld packages I have are called version 6. I think that was the zip file name. Do not remember now.

Comment: I think this question should be closed as a duplicate of xzczd's unless the central issue here is how to load a package in the Wolfram Cloud.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you want. Anyway:

```
Slinky[{a_, w_, h_}, t_] := {Cos[t] (1 + a Cos[w t]), 
                             Sin[t] (1 + a Cos[w t]), 
                             h t + a Sin[w t]} 
ParametricPlot3D[Slinky[{.4, 40, .3}, t], {t, 0, 5 Pi}, 
                 PlotPoints -> 1000, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]