# Incompability between v5-6 and v10 with Graphs and Oriented Graphs pkgs?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, packages, compatibility, mathworld

**Notice that *"[although the v6 Packages are available at the link in the answer above they are not fully compatible with v10"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43620/where-to-download-the-mathworld-package#comment316195_60628)*.** The errors [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSoVN.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZpFC.png) and [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98dKB.png) in Mathematica 10 student edition may be due to incompability between Mathematica 6 and 10. In comparison, the code in [Mathematica 5-6](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/GraphTheory/OrientedGraph.nb) probably works.

**Goal**

> I want to plot the 34 pieces of [connected oriented graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrientedGraph.html)
>
> [image]
>
> where MathWorld is providing the v5-6 code and the article on them.

**v10 without init pkg**

> When I don't load the package, I can only see the stdout without ability to modify it unless getting the errors
>
> [image]
>
> where I would similarly like to learn to generate the oriented digraphs with four pieces of vertices, and the count is 34, in Mathematica 10
>
> [image]
>
> where OrientedGraphs command is unknown in Mathematica 10 unless finding some pkg importing it or similar.

**How can I resolve the incompability with v5-6 codes in Mathematica 10?**

Comment: What if you **don't** load the package?

Comment: @J.M. added a photo without loading the package and clarified the goal.

Comment: By the way, please update the post and make it more about this missing package. It has not been shown that this has anything to do with what version of Mathematica you are using.

Comment: @C.E. How can I know that if the code is not working? Firsly, I am getting a series of errors with *"<< MathWorld`Graphs`"* (the initialization in err file [numbered 1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mSoVN.png)) where missing NautyTools and others. Secondly, the missing OrientedGraphs may be related to that. I wish there was some support email Eric's codes -- it would be so much easier to learn from MathWorld with *.nb files.

Comment: *Mathworld* Packages may be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43620/121) but there are problems loading these in version 10.  This question should IMHO focus on how to best resolve this incompatibility.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard focused as instructed, thank you for guiding.