# How to fix <<MathWorld`Graphs` package cannot be opened?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, mathworld

From http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PaleyGraph.html I downloaded this notebook http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/GraphTheory/PaleyGraph.nb.

The notebook contains the line

```
<< MathWorld`Graphs`
```

reading this packages yields a

```
$Failed
```

I have Mathematica for Windows 10.3.

Is this fixable? Is the demo notebook not ready for v10 onwards?

Any suggestions?

Comment: The package is not a builtin one, so it needs to be installed first (see above link – it's not easy to find anymore...).  There's a high chance it won't work properly in Mathematica 10 though ...

Comment: OK. That clears it up. Thank you.

Comment: Was easy to find.

Comment: Also [(116220)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/116220/121)