# Package MathWorld

Tags: packages, mathworld

I'm looking for MathWorld packages, but I can not find anywhere. I found an [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43620/where-to-download-the-mathworld-package) that came very close but did not help me.

I got lost on the site and did not find anything.

I need to use the following packages:

```
<< MathWorld`Surfaces`

<< MathWorld`Solidgeometry`

<< MathWorld`CurvilinearCoordinates`
```

Comment: I believe the packages are no longer available. So you are out of luck. They are so out-of-date that there is a good chance that they not run on any recent version of Mathematica anyway.

Comment: I have all the packages (63 of them, version 6 of mathworld), but I am not sure if one can post them for download without first getting permission from original author Eric W. Weisstein? May be you can try getting in touch with the author for copy? or if one is allowed to post them on a public site for download by others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just went searching for the MathWorld packages as well and found the post you refer to in your question ([Where to download the MathWorld package?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43620/where-to-download-the-mathworld-package)). The answer there had a link that did not go to the right place, but you can still find the packages via the Wayback Machine (and actually the answer of the aforementioned post was just updated to fix its link).

In short, you should be able to download the packages from [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120301154256/http://library.wolfram.com:80/infocenter/MathSource/4775)

However, it appears that they are not compatible with recent versions of *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, unfortunately, it has proved not feasible to keep the 5000+ MathWorld notebooks as well as the packages you refer to up-to-date with the latest *Mathematica* functionality.  As a result, I wouldn't recommend trying to use archived copies of the out-of-date packages, but if there is some particular piece of functionality you are interested in, feel free to let me know privately and I can see what I can do.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!