# Using Utilities`Typesetting` package in Mathematica version 12.3

Tags: general-utilities, mathworld

I downloaded a [notebook about conformal mapping](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/ComplexAnalysis/ConformalMapping.nb) from [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConformalMapping.html) requires a package `` Utilities`Typesetting ``, which  cannot be loaded in Mathematica 12.3.

How fix this error of missing utility in notebook of ConformalMapping.nb?

Comment: I downloaded `this` ... is not self explanatory. Please provide details/links.

Comment: Thanks @Domen for improving this question.  Jamando, in the future please do make an effort to explain your problem in detail, don't make us guess or research on your behalf. We aim to curate an encyclopedic collection of good questions and answers. Good questions inspire good answers.

Comment: @Syed You can test this notebook and see if you get the typeset error?   http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/ComplexAnalysis/ConformalMapping.nb

Comment: I get `$Failed` while evaluating ```Utilities`Typesetting```. Version: `"12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"`

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Where to download the MathWorld package?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43620/where-to-download-the-mathworld-package)  You need to extract the zip file at the very last link on [this page](http://web.archive.org/web/20130806123626/http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5087/#downloads)