# How to calculate the path covering number of a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The **path covering number** of a graph $G$ is the minimum number of vertex-disjoint paths that cover the vertices of $G$.

I am searching for a mathematica package that can calculate  path covering number of a given arbitrary graph. But unfortunately I didn't find out. We can only query the path covering number for some graphs through graph data, not for any graphs. For example,  we look at the following code.

```
seq = Table[GraphData[{"Apollonian", n}, "PathCoveringNumber"], {n, 6}]
```

The output is as follows.

```
    {1, 1, Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"], 
     Missing["NotAvailable"], Missing["NotAvailable"]}
```

So I would like to ask if there is a command for path cover number for a general graph even it is NP-hard as we known.

The following link I referred to, but unfortunately didn't find the right codes.

- https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PathCoveringNumber.html

I looked inside the notebook written by Eric W. Weisstein. It seems to use his own  **"`MathWorld`Graphs"** software package, but I do not know where to find and download and use.

Comment: The MathWorld graphs package(s) may still be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120301154256/http://library.wolfram.com:80/infocenter/MathSource/4775) as stated in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60628/4999)

Comment: I guess the linked Q&A is a duplicate of the last implicit question, but the title question may yet have a better answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for telling me about the existence of this package, but I still haven't found the function I need in the source codes. I guess doctor Eric W. Weisste 
 updated its package.  Although I sent an email to the author, I didn't get a reply. Maybe I got the wrong email address (eric@weisstein.com)?